# Initiating and calling a function inside class

Tags: python, function, class

is it acceptable to define a function and use it within class? i.e

```
class Forms:
    def myform():
        do something

    def newform():
        return myform()
        do something else
```

I am having issues with a piece of code and this seems to work better if i make myform a funtion outside class. Then call it within the newform method. IS this pythonic in any way?

Comment: The fact that you have a class called `Forms` that appears to be acting like a factory for forms is more concerning to me.  Can you give more detail on your system design here?  It'd be better to fix any ultimate causes of your issues, rather than putting a bandaid on the proximate cause.

Comment: It is actually a phone text messaging class. I did not want to bore anyone with the code but my issue is as simple as posted above. That said, i really would love to keep everything under one class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with calling another function but your syntax is not correct.

It would look something like

```
class Forms:
    def myform(self):
        #do something

    def newform(self):
        res = self.myform()
        #do something else with res
```

Comment: It may actually be that he needs a `classmethod` or `staticmethod` to work the way he intends.  Though still, that's probably because something deeper is wrong.

Comment: I certainly agree that there is A LOT more to the proper implementation of functions within a class.  But without more knowledge of the problem statement and going with "creating and calling a function within a class" I felt this was a sufficient starting point

Comment: Nice, i was missing the self.myform() part because i was calling it like an external function. Thanks for that.

Comment: That solved my question. I am still a newbie to python OOP but i like its abilities.